# C++ static code analysis which recommends Const Correctness

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis

I am looking for a static code analysis tool for C++ which will examine the code & inform me of parameters or variables which are not written to, and so can be declared const. Hopefully it will also handle double const, for a const pointer to a const object.

Gratis is good enough for me for hobby projects, although if it is gratis + free for commercial use that would be a bonus as I could try to introduce it at work. We already pay for Resharper licenses, so I doubt that they will pay for another product.

Preferably Windows, but I could run it in aLinux VM. Bonus if it integrates with Visual Studio, which is what the new project is using (***not*** Visual Studio COde).

---

[Update] in case it helps anyone reading this in future. The S.o question [Const correctness warnings c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156678/const-correctness-warnings-c) says

> there is a gnu compiler warning called -Wsuggest-attribute=const

and

> cppcheck can emit style warnings on class methods that can just as well be made const

Since [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.net/) is GPLed, I will look into that & report back here.